# how to find an element from container of pointers?

Tags: c++, find

I have container of courses*(pointer of course) and i try to search course at the countainer by its course number ! but the code below doesnt work

```
const Course findCourse(const int number) const
{
    Container<Course*, std::allocator<Course*> >::iterator ret_iterator =
        std::find_if(courses.begin(), courses.end(), FindFromPointer(number));

    if (ret_iterator == courses.end()){
        return Course::DUMMY_COURSE;
    }

    return *(ret_iterator);
}   

struct FindFromPointer
{
    FindFromPointer(int i) : n(i) { }
    bool operator()(Course * course) const { return n == course->getNumber(); }
private:
    int n;
};
```

**the container : this the schedule that have the container of courses that defined above , that mean i have class shcedule witch contain an container of courses pointer **

```
template <template <class, class> class Container>
class Schedule {
public:
    //<somthing>
    //.
    //.
private:
Container<Course*, std::allocator<Course*> >  courses;
```

Comment: "_Doesn't work_" is not a helpful fault report. What did you try? What results did you expect? and what did you get?

Comment: i try to search an course by it's course_number (this the key) , in containter that have a pointers of courses ! the function will return the elemnt if founded , else it well return DUMMY_course , the main class is the schedule that have a privete element container of courses (above)

Comment: `return *(ret_iterator);` - `*(ret_iterator)` is a pointer to `Course` but function `findCourse` returns Course itself.

Comment: *(ret_iterator) - its a course it self , because the re_iterator is an iterator of course pointer !

Comment: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Course *>>>' to 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Course *>>>'

No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>          c:\users...\schedule.h(100) : while compiling class template member function 'const Course Schedule<std::list>::findCourse(const int) const'

Comment: First, if you are using standard container (and not defining your own container with weird interface), `Container::iterator` is an iterator class to elements int the container, `Course*`, so `*(ret_iterator)` is `Course*` type, not `Course`.

Comment: Second, `findCourse` is a `const` member function of `class Schedule` (is not?), so it only can access to the `const` members of the object. `courses` is a data member of the same class, so `courses.begin()`, `courses.end()` and `find_if()` function will return `const_iterator`, not `iterator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning `*(ret_iterator)` from function `findCourse` causes compilation error, because `*(ret_iterator)` is a pointer to `Course`. iterator's `operator*` returns a reference to element of a container and an element of your container is pointer to `Course`. The correct code should be like this:

```
return *( *ret_iterator );
```

or more clearly:

```
Course * ret_pointer = *ret_iterator;
return * ret_pointer;
```

The other problem: function `findCourse` is declared as `const`, that's why all members of class `Schedule` are `const` inside this function. When you call `std::find_if` with `courses.begin()` the const version of `begin()` is called. It returns **const_iterator** and `std::find_if` returns **const_iterator** respectively. But... you assign it to **iterator** and it should cause a compiler error. The correct code is:

```
Container<Course*, std::allocator<Course*> >::const_iterator ret_iterator =
    std::find_if(courses.begin(), courses.end(), FindFromPointer(number));
```

or you can remove `const` qualifier from declaration of `findCourse`.

Comment: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Course *>>>' to 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Course *>>>' No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous 1> c:\users...\schedule.h(100) : while compiling class template member function 'const Course Schedule<std::list>::findCourse(const int) const' –